# xbap application not showing image when running outside from VS

Tags: wpf

I've made a "WPF Browser Application" project, on my login screen i have putted one image tag which is showing image ok when i am running the application by pressing F5 from VS2010

but when i run the xbap from debug folder the image is not showing, I have also tried by putting my image in the same debug folder but no use.

any suggestion what i have to correct when setting image

xaml

Answer (score 0):

From Project->Security settings I changed "This is a partial trust application" to "This is a full trust application" and now it is showing image when i run the .xbap from bin/Debug folder.